# Is there a way to programmatically control Publift ad display or hide conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, ads

**Context:**

- We're using Publift (an ad bidding platform) for advertisement on our site.
- We would like to have the ad display/hide upon user subscription status (paid / non-paid)

**Problem:**

- We tried to load/unload the ad script conditionally and it works in most cases. Even though, when we load it, a few external scripts (loaded by Publift) will add anonymous listeners to the DOM, and we have no way to get rid of it. After that, user comes into the paid mode, the listener still exists and show the ad unintendedly.

Anyone experience with with similar ad platform and figure out better approach? Appreciate it with any of your help!

Comment: Presumably if you include any of their code on your page you'll get ads, if you don't you won't. You are in complete control as to whether you include their code on your page, so you should make it include the code if it's a subscribed user from the back end of your site.